# Can I order divs randomly at any point on a page using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, random

Is it possible to place divs on a page in a random position on a page on load? If so, how? I'm getting a little stuck! or at least point me in the right direction.

I would like the page to load up with the divs I have already created in a random position. I don't mean in a random order like 3,5,2,7,9,1,4 etc in a row or column.

More like this example:
[random images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfXNV.jpg)

In the above example the small red and white squares are draggable and the 2 larger ones are pots for the squares to be dragged in to.

Can the red and white smaller squares be randomly placed?

examples I have previously found seem to explain how to make divs randomly fade in or change after time to another random image.

Comment: Can it be done? Yes.

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: use canvas and create rectangles

Comment: @NadeemmnnMohd That's one way to do it. It's also possible to do this with divs and absolute or fixed positioning.

Comment: yes http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp see this example for drag and drop and create dynamic rectangles and use fill image in it and drag it and drop it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can, here's a small example to get you started.

Find the width and height of the window, iterate over each div giving each an absolute position along with a random top and left property.

```
// get width and height of the page
var pwidth = $(window).width();
var pheight = $(window).height();

// loop through each div 
$('div').each(function(){
    // get random x and y positon
    var x = Math.random() * pwidth;
    var y = Math.random() * pheight;
    // set style options
    $(this).css('position', 'absolute').css('left', x).css('top', y);
});
```

This example doesn't randomize size or take the size of the element into account.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

by loop for each div you mean i cant place 2 div names in to the same function?

Comment: `$('...')` is a selector, it can select more than one element. Place class name (eq. `$('.rand')`), ID, tag name, etc. like you would do in CSS. `.each()` function will loop through each of those elements and do whatever is specified in function that has been passed as a first parameter. eq. `$('.select-these').each(function(){ /* do this for each selected element */  });`

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. its got what im looking for about 90% of the way and I would like to work out the rest. 

Many thanks for the help.